# Typescript: Cannot find type definition file for 'bin', 'src', 'test'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm brand new to the front-end and I'm likely very dumb. However, in a nutshell, if I do this

```
yarn add @mapbox/polyline
```

I suddenly get all kinds of helpful errors like this when I `yarn start`:

```
undefined
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Cannot find type definition file for 'bin'.  TS2688

undefined
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Cannot find type definition file for 'src'.  TS2688

index.js:1 undefined
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Cannot find type definition file for 'test'.  TS2688
```

Ok cool. So I've royally broken this (`git`) branch (been there!), so let's just switch back to the working `master` branch... but `yarn start` yields the same errors on `master` now! It's as if the mere act of typing `yarn add @mapbox/polyline` corrupts something locally so badly that it's unrecoverable. I end up having to clone my repo again and start fresh.

(Since I'm using Typescript, I also tried adding types `yarn add @types/mapbox__polyline`... this does nothing to alleviate my pain.)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: do you specifiy `@types` in your package name? (you should not)

Comment: @FrançoisRomain yeah as said

Comment: Or maybe there is a package specifying a `@types` like here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956#issuecomment-430849185

Comment: @FrançoisRomain yeah saw that. It doesn't matter, it's the mere act of `yarn add @mapbox/polyline`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error happens because you have "garbage" inside `node_modules/@types` and/or your `tsconfig.json` is not configured properly. In order to understand exactly what's going on you need to know the following about TypeScript:

There are two fields in `tsconfig.json` related to this issue: ["typeRoots"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) and ["types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [],
    "types": []
  }
}
```

`"typeRoots"` specifies where TypeScript will be looking for "types" (I'll talk about what a type is shortly). If there is no `"typeRoots"` in `tsconfig.json` then TypeScript looks for types in `node_modules/@types/`.

So, what is considered a "type"? A type is a [folder](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956#issuecomment-561840216) with `index.d.ts` file inside of it (or a folder with `package.json` inside of it specifying a different path/name to the type file).

`"types"` limits `"typeRoots"` by allowing TypeScript to look for types only into the folders which names are specified in `"typeRoots"`. E.g. if your `tsconfig.json` contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ['./node_modules/@types'],
    "types": ['aaaaaa'],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

then only `./node_modules/@types/aaaaaa` will be used for types, and `./node_modules/@types/bbbbbb` will be ignored (actually, it will be only partly ignored, only globals inside of it will be ignored, the other information about types inside of it will be used as usual).

So, in your case (assuming you don't have `"typeRoots"` in your `tsconfig.json`) it's very likely you get "Cannot find type definition file for" error because you have garbage (i.e. [subdirectories that do not contain index.d.ts files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956#issuecomment-430849185)) inside your `node_modules/@types` after running `yarn add @mapbox/polyline`. This would also explain why this error is not fixed when you switch git branches (because git doesn't track `node_modules`).

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it helps anyone else, adding `"types": []` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` fixed it.

I have no clear idea why this works. I just decided to try the suggestion found in [this bug report](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_typescript/issues/449), which I'm not sure is related.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would add the `@types\mapbox\polyline` package.
However the typings may not exist

If you want to suppress these (if the types don't exist) you can add a file to your project

`mapbox-polyline.d.ts` (or whichever name you choose as long as it ends with `.d.ts`)

with the current contents

`declare module '@mapbox/polyline'`

Update: I've tested adding this package and 
`yarn add mapbox/polyline` appears to import it. 
However the git repo says that  polyline has been deprecated in favour of `@mapbox/polyline` so it's possible the typings authors havent caught up.

Update: I'd suggest to uninstall the packages you have right now, then reinstall with the latest version of @mapbox/polyline with `yarn add @mapbox/polyline`, then supress the typescrpt warnings by adding the ambient declaration above for now.

Comment: did you try without the `@` ? usually only typing librarys are prefixed with and. e.g.  `yarn add mapbox/polyline`

Comment: the typings may not be up to date with the actual repo. I've had a look at the src in github and that library is so tiny you could probably write the typings for it yourself in a short amount of time if you wished

Comment: did you add the js in the way i described above?